# /bin/sh: 1: C:xamppphpphp.exe: not Found

Tags: php, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, xampp, wsl-2

I am using WSL2, Ubuntu 20.04 and running VSCode. I am using the Code Runner extension in VSCode and XAMPP on Windows

I set the path to php.exe in the Windows Environment Variables.

I have the following in the VSCode settings.json for code runner

```
 "code-runner.executorMap": {
        "javascript": "node",
        "php": "C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe",
        "python": "python",
        "perl": "perl",
        "ruby": "C:\\Ruby23-x64\\bin\\ruby.exe",
        "go": "go run",
        "html": "\"C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe\"",
        "java": "cd $dir && javac $fileName && java $fileNameWithoutExt",
        "c": "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    },
```

I have a program in the editor called index.php.  I right click in the VSCode editor to select "Run Code"

In the VSCode terminal's output window I get this error message:

```
[Running] C:\xampp\php\php.exe "/home/johnr/xproj/index.php"
/bin/sh: 1: C:xamppphpphp.exe: not found

[Done] exited with code=127 in 0.039 seconds
```

1. Why and I getting the error message?
2. Why does the path in the bin statement not show the slashed between the directories (C:xamppphpphp instead of C:\xampp\php\php.exe)?

I have tried various configuration changes based on Google search results but nothing has changed this error message.

Except when I changes sh dash to sh bash and got this message instead

```
[Running] C:\xampp\php\php.exe "/home/johnr/xproj/index.php"
/bin/sh: C:xamppphpphp.exe: not found

[Done] exited with code=127 in 0.039 seconds
```

The only difference is the 1: was not present after the /bin/sh:

Comment: `VSCode` is running on Ubuntu, a flavor of Linux. You're attempting to run Windows-style paths and commands on Linux, which will not work.

Comment: @anyber To which one of the paths in the question are you referring to?

Comment: Anything that starts with C:\ is a Windows path, and won't work on linux

Answer (score 1):

I think WSL needs **Unix-like** paths, so for example your php path should be

`"php": "/mnt/c/xampp/php/php.exe",`

instead of

`"php": "C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe",`

Same would probably apply to ruby.

Answer (score 0):

While @Caellion is on the right track in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76094802/11810933), I *don't* recommend this.

In general, either use the *Windows* toolchain in Windows, or the Linux toolchain in WSL, but mixing the two isn't a good idea.

Since you are using the Windows XAMPP stack, just run VSCode from Windows *without* the WSL2 extension.  This should allow it to pick up and run the Windows PHP interpreter correctly using the Windows path.

The Windows version of PHP (and other development tools) is not going to understand Linux paths, processes, native code modules, etc.

Conversely, the Linux/WSL version of these tools isn't going to understand the Windows paths, processes, native code modules, etc.

It's sometimes possible, in a very simple project, to combine the two, but as a general rule it's far better to keep to one architecture or the other.

Comment: The VSCode is on Ubuntu which is on WSL2 on Windows.  The XAMPP stack is on Windows. Code Runner is an extension on VSCode.

Which path shoudl I be changing

Comment: To keep a single architecture I will need to use a web server on Ubuntu that can be started from VSCode. It will need to run PHP, HTML, JavaScript, CSS, and others. I was told that XAMPP would do the trick. 

Any suggestions as to which web server I can run on Ubuntu??

Comment: The only change you should need to make is to run VSCode under Windows (from the Start menu) rather than from inside Ubuntu.  Alternatively, you could install the Ubuntu XAMPP stack, since it sounds like that's what you want anyway.  Then you would continue to run `code .` from inside Ubuntu, and VSCode (using the WSL2 extension) will find all of the necessary XAMPP *Linux* versions.

Comment: @Guy60 That said, I'm not sure about Code Runner with WSL2.